# Faye web socket

Tags: node.js, websocket, faye

I'm new with faye web socket, and I tried to set up a server and a client to exchange information. Unfortunately I'm missing something and I can't get on the client the messages sent from the server. 
This is my server.js:

```
     var faye = require('faye');

      var Router = require('node-simple-router');
      var router = new Router();
      var server = require('http').createServer(router);
      var port = 5000;

      var bayeux = new faye.NodeAdapter({mount: '/faye/calls'});
      bayeux.attach(server);

      // Launch the server
      server.listen(port, function() {
           console.log('Listening on ' + port);
                  setInterval(function(){
                             bayeux.getClient().publish('/faye/calls', {text: 'Hello'});
         },3000);
```

And is my client.js

```
         var faye = require('faye');

         var client = new faye.Client('http://localhost:5000/faye', {
                  timeout: 600,
                  retry: 5
         });

        var sub =  client.subscribe('/calls', function(message) {
                console.log('message:' + message);
        });

        sub.then(function() {
               console.log('overall Subscription is now active!');
        });
```

Can somebody please tell me what I'm missing?
Thanks very much

Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your paths are to blame:

```
var bayeux = new faye.NodeAdapter({mount: '/faye/calls'});
```

should mount to `/faye`:

```
var bayeux = new faye.NodeAdapter({mount: '/faye'});
```

and

```
bayeux.getClient().publish('/faye/calls', {text: 'Hello'});
```

Should actually publish to `/calls`

```
bayeux.getClient().publish('/calls', {text: 'Hello'});
```

That appears to resolve the issue for me:

```
overall Subscription is now active!
message:[object Object]
message:[object Object]
message:[object Object]
```